# z3py: Symbolic expressions cannot be cast to concrete Boolean values?

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py

```py
from z3 import *
x = Real('x')
s = Solver()
s.add(x > 1 or x < -1)
print(s.check())
if s.check() == sat:
    print(s.model())
```

I want to solve a or expressions , how can i do it?
when z3 told me "Symbolic expressions cannot be cast to concrete Boolean values"

Answer (score 0):

Python's `or` is not symbolic aware. Instead, use `z3py`'s `Or`:

```py
from z3 import *
x = Real('x')
s = Solver()
s.add(Or(x > 1, x < -1))
r = s.check()
print(r)
if r == sat:
    print(s.model())
```

This prints:

```
sat
[x = -2]
```

Note that I'd also avoid two separate calls to `check`, by storing the result in a variable first. (Which I called `r` above.) In general, the second call to `check` will be cheap since you haven't added any constraints after the first, but this makes the intention clearer.

Comment: oh，you are so kind! thanks.

Comment: hi , bro! If I want to konw more about how ti use z3, where there is books or documents I can reference?

Comment: The proper way to indicate an answer has helped you is to "accept" it. Click on the checkmark next to it.

Re learning z3py: Start here: https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm